# Обновление файла локализации в Django без перетирания

Tags: django, locale

Делаю локализацию сайта.

- Выполняю команду: `makemessages -l ru`;
- Получаю `django.po` файл;
- Редактирую этот файл;
- Нахожу на сайте непереведённое слово;
- Оборачиваю это слово в `{% trans 'word' %}`.
- Запускаю повторно `makemessages`;

После запуска `makemessages` повторно - все переводы из `django.po` стираются.

Как **не перетирать** имеющиеся переводы в файле `django.po`, а **дополнять** новыми?

**UPD:**
Перетирание вызывает сочетание параметров `makemessages -l ru -e html`

До команды:

```
#: env/lib/python3.5/site-packages/sorl/thumbnail/admin/compat.py:61
msgid "Clear image"
msgstr "Удалить картинку"
```

После команды:

```
#~ msgid "Clear image"
#~ msgstr "Удалить картинку"
```

Структура:

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Команда `makemessages` запускается из ИДЕ от `manage.py` проекта.

Расположения сгенерированного `django.po`:

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Строка из `base.py`:

```
LOCALE_PATHS = [os.path.join(BASE_DIR, 'stroyprombeton/locale')]
```

Comment: Нет, они не должны стираться и ни в одном из моих проектов никогда не стирались. Какую версию Django используете и можно ли посмотреть на проблемный проект целиком? (Можно без частей, которые не влияют на суть проблемы, лишь бы я смог у себя эту проблему воспроизвести)

Comment: @andreymal Я обновил вопрос. Запуск с параметром `-e html` изменяет файл, как я описал в UPD. Версия Django 1.10.

Comment: А зачем вы `-e html` дописываете? Вполне логично, что он по `py` файлам тогда не проходится, не видит строки оттуда и вполне логично считает имеющиеся в `django.po` строки ненужными

Comment: `-e html` дописываю для того, чтобы пройтись только по шаблонам. Ведь именно шаблоны я и изменяю. В итоге: уже переведённые слова в шаблонах команда оборачивает в комментарий (делает неактивными)

Comment: А зачем вам проходиться только по шаблонам? Почему бы не убрать `-e html` и не радоваться жизни?)

Comment: Мне не нужны в `django.po` файле переводы для, например, `msgid "Enter a valid IPv6 address."` :)
В документации о таком поведении я ничего не нашел. Баг или фича...?

Comment: А зачем вы тогда оборачиваете в `trans` ненужные вам фразы?)

Comment: Думаете я полез в `env/lib/python3.5/site-packages/django/core/validators.py:270` и сам обернул там, что-то?

Comment: Давайте [продолжим обсуждение в чате](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/55324/discussion-between-andreymal-and-yozhezhi).

Comment: @andreymal You must have 20 reputation on The Stack Exchange Network. Сорян.

Comment: Ну блин, в общем makemessages не должен лезть в env и у меня никогда не лез, он должен лезть только в ваши собственные файлы, в связи с чем подозреваю, что вы организовали проект неправильно, можно его структуру фаилов-каталогов и в каком каталоге makemessages запускаете?

Comment: Почему не должен лезть туда, если во внутренних файлах используется `ugettext_lazy`? Например, `raise Http404(_("No week specified"))`. Не отрицаю, что чего-то я не шарю :)

Comment: Потому что файлы django.po для всего внутри env уже созданы до вас и входят в стандартную поставку джанги, и вам нет никакой необходимости переводить это всё ещё раз и следовательно лезть команде makemessages внутрь env нет никакого смысла, дайте структуру проекта

Comment: А где расположен ваш django.po?

Comment: @andreymal UPD.

Comment: Предлагаю или запускать `../manage.py makemessages -l ru` внутри каталога `stroyprombeton`, или запускать `./manage.py makemessages -l ru --ignore env`, тогда вроде должно быть всё норм и надобность в `-e html` пропадёт

Comment: @andreymal Спасибо! Оформи, пожалуйста, как ответ. Я поправлю что нужно и помечу, что он решил мою проблему.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Команда `makemessages` задумана для создания файла переводов `django.po` из ВСЕХ файлов ВСЕГО проекта (или отдельного приложения, если перейти в каталог с ним). Соответственно, он *заменяет*, а не дополняет файл переводов, так и задумывалось.

Соответственно, `-e html` указывает команде просматривать файлы только с расширением html, в итоге только они и будут считаться для `makemessages` всем проектом, а все фразы, которых в html-файлах нет, будут убраны из po-файла.

Собственно, достаточно убрать `-e html`, чтобы фразы не убирались.

Однако `makemessages` обрабатывает все файлы в текущей директории, а, как выяснилось в комментариях, в текущей директории есть и виртуальное окружение `env`, в которой установлена джанга, и `makemessages` добирается и туда и выковыривает все внутренние фразы для перевода. Но в этом нет никакой необходимости: переводы внутренних фраз уже лежат в `env/lib/python3.5/site-packages/django/conf/locale/ru/LC_MESSAGES/django.po` (и ещё в 12 файлах) и будут автоматически подхвачены джангой, и нет никакой необходимости переводить их повторно.

Чтобы `makemessages` не лез в каталог `env`, можно:

- запускать его в каталоге с приложением: `cd stroyprombeton; ../manage.py makemessages -l ru`
- добавить каталог в игнорируемые: `./manage.py makemessages -l ru --ignore env`

P.S. Рекомендую для удобства создать или дополнить `Makefile`:

```
.PHONY: messages compilemessages

PYTHON?=python

messages:
    cd stroyprombeton && $(PYTHON) ../manage.py makemessages -l ru

compilemessages:
    cd stroyprombeton && $(PYTHON) ../manage.py compilemessages
```

<sup>(у compilemessages опции --ignore почему-то нет)</sup>

Тогда достаточно будет выполнить команду `make messages` для обновления `django.po` и `make compilemessages` для создания файлов `mo`.

Comment: Спасибо! В итоге я создал django-команду в которой вызывается `call_command('makemessages', '-l', 'ru', '-i', 'env/lib')`